# mobile scroll command is not working in appium 1.5 for iOS application

Tags: python, ios, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

Today I updated my `appium` to `1.5` everything is running fine except the `mobile: scrollTo` command.

```
el = getattr(driver, 'find_element_by_' + locator_type)(locator_path)
driver.execute_script("mobile: scrollTo", {"element": el.id})
```

this code is not working anymore and I am getting an error:

> WebDriverException: Message: Unknown command, all the mobile commands
>   except scroll have been removed.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue resolved

Use this code in Appium 1.5
﻿

```
driver.execute_script("mobile: scroll", {"direction": 'down', 'element': el})
```